# PropertyChanged event not Handled properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to get my property changed event handler working, and I've checked with the dubugger the OnPropertyChanged method is being called, but it's not invoking the method like I was expecting it to.

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _characterSelection = new CharacterSelectionViewModel();
        _characterSelection.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(characterSelection_PropertyChanged);
    }

    private void characterSelection_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Character"))
        {
            _character = _characterSelection.Character;
            _currentView = _newCharacter;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}

public class CharacterSelectionViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private void newCharacter()
    {
        CharacterSaver.SaveCharacter(CharacterName, _character);
        OnPropertyChanged("Character");
    }
}
```

I've stepped through this with the debugger, the constructor for `MainViewModel()` gets called, and adds the `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.
At this point, `_characterSelection's PropertyChanged` event has this value: (From the locals tab in the debugger)

```
{Method = {Void characterSelection_PropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)}}
```

Once `newCharacter` method in the `CharacterSelectionViewModel` gets called, it calls `OnPropertyChanged`.
At this point, `_characterSelection's PropertyChanged` event has this value:

```
{Method = {Void OnPropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)}}
```

The `OnPropertyChanged` event gets to the `handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));` line, but `characterSelection_PropertyChanged()` is never invoked. No errors are thrown.

What did I miss? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you appear to be raising the event *before* you add the handler. There's no way that's going to work.

Comment: I just ran your code, and the event was raised and called the handler in `MainViewModel` just fine.  How are you calling `newCharacter`?  We need more information to solve this.

Comment: newCharacter is called by a button press, invoked with an ICommand. The handler is added during intialization of the page.

Comment: How are you binding things up?  I just created a dummy WPF page with the `MainViewModel` being the `DataContext`, and created a command on the `CharacterSelectionViewModel`.  I bound that command to a button (I exposed the `_characterSelection` field as an `internal` property, such that the binding was `CharacterSelection.NewCharacterCommand`), and the command calls `newCharacter()`, and everything was raised as expected.

Comment: Thank you! The datacontext was the problem. I had:

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:CharacterSelectionViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

in my CharacterSelectionView file, so it was creating a separate instance of the class. if you put that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Done - glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have the binding set up such that you are having a separate instance of `CharacterSelectionViewModel` instead of the instance on `MainViewModel`.  Check your bindings to ensure that you're properly bound to the `MainViewModel`, and that you're utilizing its instance of `CharacterSelectionViewModel` for your `ICommand` binding to ensure that the event that you're subscribing to (on the correct instance) is properly raised.